# what does INCLUDE_CHECK do in php?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Hi I am new in php and when I came across define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true); I was not able to understand what it is for?

Pls. explain.

Thanks!
Sagar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a constant that is being used by that application later. Define() is used to create these constants. Typically this is used for configuration data. To use this constant later, you simply use the string INCLUDE_CHECK in code like it were a variable without the $.

so

```
if(INCLUDE_CHECK)
{
// Do code that only should happen if you want it to.
}
```

Comment: They can be. They can hold any non-complex data structure. String, float, int, bool. They can't hold objects or arrays. If you are really very new to PHP, I would just read php.net's entry on Define() and if that is too hard to understand, come back to it later. This is a moderate-advanced aspect of PHP.

Comment: I'm glad! Good Luck! And if you want to give back, maybe select this answer as the correct one?

Comment: I am selecting it but it says will be selected after 2 mins. Thanks again and I will select this ans.

Answer (score 0):

INCLUDE_CHECK is not a feature of PHP itself, only of some code that someone has written in PHP.  The first hit [on google](http://pastebin.com/TrHUF3ir) shows us a configuration file that a user is attempting to protect by checking if the variable is defined.

The approach taken in the sniped I found on google is like this

- a file which can be referenced directly (e.g. http://example.com/foo.php) will define INCLUDE_CHECK and then include a file that checks INCLUDE_CHECK, e.g. config.php; because foo.php has already defined it, this will work correctly
- if a user accesses config.php directly (e.g. http://example.com/config.php) then INCLUDE_CHECK will not have been defined, so an error will occur, preventing the user from running the script.

The following examples should make this clearer

foo.php

```
<?php
defined('INCLUDE_CHECK', true);
require_once 'config.php';
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
if (!defined('INCLUDE_CHECK')) { die ('invalid access'); }
echo 'Hello World!';
?>
```

If a user accesses config.php directly, then INCLUDE_CHECK is not defined, so the script will die with the message invalid access.  If a user accesses foo.php, it will define INCLUDE_CHECK *then* include config.php, which will then echo Hello World.

This is a pretty crap way of protecting a configuration file, btw; see [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300800/how-to-ignore-access-to-php-files-with-mod-rewrite/4300900#4300900) for a more simple and reliable approach.

Comment: Thanks for replying! This was really helpful but still doesn't understood the how protection is done for configuration file in the google link of your ans...

Comment: I have changed my answer to explain how the example found on google works.  As I said, it's not a very good approach to take to protect these files.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to DampeS8N Answer which is correct one.

I read php.net's link https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php
and below example makes it clear that any value can be used inside define function for defining variable as constant and INCLUDE_CHECK was just a variable which I thought as some kind of php feature ;)

```
<?php
define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
echo CONSTANT; // outputs "Hello world."
echo Constant; // outputs "Constant" and issues a notice.

define("GREETING", "Hello you.", true);
echo GREETING; // outputs "Hello you."
echo Greeting; // outputs "Hello you."

?>
```

@DampeS8N pls. comment if wrong!

Thanks to all of you for your answers!