# How can i redirect users (with mod_rewrite) to 404 page if they type in an existing file, or folder?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How can i redirect users (with mod_rewrite) to 404 page if they type in an existing file, or folder ?

Example:

I have 2 files at my site:
www.example.com/index.php - The homepage
www.example.com/about.php - The about page

I don't want to be accesible at index.php and about.php. I want it this way only:
www.example.com/
www.example.com/about

And i want to work this way for every file i create.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore access to php files with mod_rewrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300800/how-to-ignore-access-to-php-files-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

Just redirect the pages that you want to a PHP page that sends a 404 header.

For instance:

```
RewriteRule pageToRedirect.htm errorPage.php [L]
```

errorPage.php will have whatever you like in it and specify:

```
header("Status: 404 Not Found");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteRule .* 404.html [R=404,L]
```

This will rewrite all requests to a file or directory that exists to 404.html with a 404 status code.

Comment: This actually redirects all files **found** to the `404.html` document. It should be `!-d` without `[OR]` and `!-f`.

Comment: @goreSplatter isn't that exactly what OP asks for? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @goreSplatter, think thats what the OP wants

Comment: This doesn't redirect files to `404.html`. [it redirects them to Apache's default 404 page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#redirect) (and the `[L]` isn't needed). If you want to redirect to your own 404 page, you should do a regular redirect and set the header yourself.

Comment: @Maxxon `[R=404]` is only supported since Apache 2.2.

Comment: @Maxxon: check your server log. Also check the permissions of your `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

I answered the same question of yours the other day; you should try to read it again, as it's easier to do, more maintainable and more secure than mod_rewrite.  You didn't seem to understand, as you marked the wrong answer correct.

Here is [a link to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300800/4300848#4300848) and my answer.  Look it over again and ask if you need clarification.