# PHP script protection

Tags: php, security, apache

I had a terrifying issue a few days ago. I was installing updates on my ubuntu server, which is a hosts for about 10 websites. During the update, something went wrong, and apaches `mod_php` became disabled. As a result, PHP support was gone, and for a few minutes (until I figured what's wrong) users got an invitation to download PHP scripts, instead of seeing a website. Needless to say, there is nothing worse then exposing your script sources to the whole world, especially when database credentials are kept inside.

**The question:** How can I configure apache, so this situation would not be possible in the future? What lines should I add to apache2.conf, so that PHP files could not be downloaded, if mod_php is disabled?

Comment: I think you should probably just down your apache when you are upgrading =|

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add the following to the .htaccess in the root directory

```
php_admin_flag engine on
```

In this case user will get HTTP 500 error trying to read any file from this dir and below because no module defines php_admin_flag directive in case mod_php is off.

Comment: Interesting approach; I think what I propose below is still a better approach, as it will work without .htaccess files being enabled at all.

Comment: Thanks, great idea. Will the work in a global configuration (apache2.conf)? I don't want to forget to edit a .htaccess file and end up with the same result...

Comment: @Silver Light: yes, it will work in apache2.conf also, but disabling PHP module in this case will prevent the whole server from starting

Answer (score 5):

A more secure approach would be simply to not put things you don't want accessed in the document root in the first place.  See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300800/4300848#4300848) which provides more detail; the basic idea is, if you don't ever want a file accessed via URL, don't put the damn file in a URL accessible place.  99% of your app code should not be under the document root; then it doesn't really matter what you do to your apache/php setup, you're still safe.

Comment: A very good advice, thanks. This does not quite solve the problem, because I at least must put index.php in the document root, am I not?

Comment: Yes, but you're not trying to protect that; or rather, nothing important would be there.  My index.php has about 2 lines, which just creates a controller and calls it; this takes care of everything else.